# Convert files to MP4 in sub directories

Tags: command-line, video-conversion

I have my film and series collection in one directory, which obviously has a lot of sub directories and a lot of different formats. It's constantly being added to by all of us here. What I'd like to do is make a script that I can run occasionally when one or all of us has added in new stuff that will search for files in that directory/sub directories and convert them to a format that kodi/xbmc can stream to my trusty old xbox 360. I'm running Gnome 16.04, I'm not sure if that's relevant or not.

So far I've found the code to convert the actual files;

```
for i in *mkv; do ffmpeg -i $i -vcodec copy -acodec copy "$i.mp4"; done
```

and the files are all located in;

```
/media/dave/Seagate Expansion Drive/Media
```

So, these are the problems I'm left with.

- Is mp4 the best way to go? Googling this hasn't really cleared it up for me, there are a million different opinions! So far it'll play some MP4's but not all.
- How to adapt that little line of code to search for more than just mkv - there are mpeg, avi, wmv, mov, everything you can think of! Would I need to just repeat that line of code for each different file type?
- How to make it search the subdirectories
- How to make it delete the original file only if the conversion if successful
- How can I set kodi/xbmc to load on start up already minimised?

Any help, suggestions or pointers to get this sorted would be REALLY appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

> How to make it search the subdirectories

Use `find`.

> How to adapt that little line of code to search for more than just
>   mkv

Use `-iregex` option with `find`.

> How to make it delete the original file only if the conversion if
>   successful

You need an `if` switch.

Putting it all together:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' movie ; do
    echo "Found: $movie"

    convert_command="ffmpeg -i '$movie' -vcodec copy -acodec copy '$movie.mp4'"

    if bash -c "$convert_command" ; then
        echo "Converted to mp4"
        rm "$movie"
    else
        echo "Convertation failed"
    fi
done < <(find . -type f -iregex '.*\(mkv\|mpeg\|avi\|wmv\|mov\)' -print0)
```

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8677566/1494770) answer to create loop based in `find` output.

Advantages and disadvantages of mp4 and kodi/xbmc minimizing on startup are independent questions, I suggest you to create separate posts for each of them.

Comment: That's fantastic, thank you @teksisto - it kicks up a fairly lengthy error however which seems to center around a library config mismatch. It won't let me copy the whole thing in because it's massive - it looks like it's asking for config parameters. It ends it all with 'No such file or directory
Convertation failed'  -  I'm honestly  not sure how much help that is to you!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that file names can include spaces. See updated version.

Comment: Answering this question, I realized that my usual approach with for/find loop is wrong and works only because my files usually have no spaces in names.

Comment: Thank you @teksisto - it's still crashing out on me though. I think the problem might lie in the ffmpeg bit itself as that doesn't seem to work any-which-way.  Would it be possible to swap that maybe for the av version do you think?  I'll put another question up to try and figure out what it's deal is, but if I can find a fix that works with something else (even handbrake-cli?) then I'm still ahead of the game!

Comment: I assumed that your `ffmeg` command is valid, and tested script with `cp $movie $movie.converted`.